# PHP Server Proxy to use in Windows Server Plesk Hosting without command access

Tags: windows, proxy, server, plesk

Im searching for some time for a php proxy application to run in my hosting running Plesk over Windows Server.

What I really need is a personal proxy server using my hosting services that allows me to use a server:port configuration on my applications. I dont want a online proxy page, because I need a proxy to setup server:port on my application.

its a "light proxy", obviously I dont wanna burn the ip used for my hosted website.

I tryed search for squid, tinyproxy, 3proxy, miniproxys and even Glype, but some are just for linux and other provide just a online proxy page, not a port config.

I don't have command prompt access that is why Im looking for a PHP solution, but it could be any solution than PHP to.

Thanks in advance guys!

Marcelo

Comment: Please Help.

Im just a beginner in this forum and I realize that, but can someone help me please.
This forum helped me a lot in the past just using searches. This is the first thread I have on my own.

Comment: A Little help here please!